# logarithmic scale in Python makes the yscale disappear

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot these values with logarithmic scale.
I set the `xscale` to be logarithmic and it works but once I change the `yscale` to logarithmic the plot is empty

```
1 1.3983122938704392e-24
2 1.2825051378519808e-24
3 5.5230816485933455e-25
4 1.6920941401196186e-25
5 4.2785540109054585e-26
6 9.573610853721047e-27
7 1.9686256356892187e-27
8 3.805287950338823e-28
9 7.016068861317399e-29
10 1.2462784636632535e-29
11 2.1480378257342412e-30
12 3.6112402884779174e-31
13 5.945542463839695e-32
14 9.615996905704895e-33
15 1.5315555893729047e-33
16 2.4069535816407215e-34
17 3.7385510098146993e-35
18 5.7467571042464316e-36
19 8.75215314794321e-37
20 1.3218825579234095e-37
21 1.981570594514771e-38
22 2.950315675351239e-39
23 4.365487327673689e-40
24 6.422908401651751e-41
25 9.400843198676917e-42
26 1.3693535952403045e-42
27 1.985800585870847e-43
28 2.8679212082869596e-44
29 4.126063379717258e-45
30 5.9149958576112206e-46
31 8.451319914553198e-47
32 1.2037551958686832e-47
33 1.7095383153201586e-48
34 2.4211547577096363e-49
35 3.4200992669649083e-50
36 4.819376551228057e-51
37 6.775436972956835e-52
38 9.504553221721265e-53
39 1.3305264659826585e-53
```

with using this code

```
plt.scatter(A, B)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylim('log')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because you use 'ylim' instead of 'yscale' at the third line of your code.
You can try this :

```
plt.scatter(A, B)
plt.xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```